# Decimal expansion of rational number

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion, number-systems

I just have a question about rational numbers and their decimal expansion. I have x, which is an rational number and that $x=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b$ is not equal $0$. How can I show that the decimal expansion of $x$ repeats?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Study carefully the division algorithm. There are only a  finite number of possible remainders at each step, hence, if the algorithm never stops, …

Comment: The decimal expansion does not necessarily repeats, take for example $a=1$ , $b=2$ the decimal expansion is $.5$ and it does not repeat itself, unless you mean that after the $5$ the $0$ repeats itself.

Comment: If $a/b$ is rational then it normalized decimal expansion is periodic.

Comment: @Jonathaniui you are not considering the infinite zeros or the fact that $0.4999999...=0.50000...$

Comment: Certainly, I forgot that.